# Modify ToolboxItem during drag and drop

Tags: c#, winforms

I am working with the DesignSurface class and I have run into a frustrating problem that I can't seem to figure out.  I am dragging items from my Toolbox and dropping them onto my form without a problem but I want to modify the properties of these items as they are placed onto the DesignSurface.  So, for example, if I drag a label onto the DesignSurface I may change the value of the BackColor of the control.  I know that ToolboxItem exposes CreateComponents()  which takes an optional parameter of properties but this is called by the lower level API and I don't see where or how to override it so I can supply my own values. Does anyone have any ideas?  Thanks!

Comment: Do you mean there are some items on your `DesignSurface` and you want to modify some properties of those items at design time (via the Properties window)? What does your `DesignSurface` look like? Is it something like a `Panel`? Your question is not clear enough to me.

Comment: The DesignSurface is a UserControl.  What I am actually trying to do is that when the user drops a control onto the UserControl I want to modify some of the properties of that control before it is actually displayed on the surface.  Certainly if I wanted to modify the values of the control after they were on the DesignSurface I will just configure a PropertyGrid.

Comment: That's a little strange to me? Why do you have to do so?

Comment: The app I am working on is basically trying to reproduce a small set of the functionality found in the report designer inside Visual Studio so it can be exposed to users. The issue I am trying to solve is that the toolbox actually contains report field names and when the user drags and drops the field on the DesignSurface I need a way to maintain that x label is actually the Name field in the dataset. I haven't been able to think of a better way to handle this and, quite frankly, this is the first time I've ever been asked to host a runtime designer so it is challenging.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

While I feel that this is a bit "hacky" I don't necessarily know that it is wrong (and if it is technically "wrong" please leave me some feedback on best practices!) and it solved the problem at hand.

What I ended up doing was extending ToolboxItem based on an MSDN article that I read.

```
public class SurfaceToolboxItem : ToolboxItem
{
    private delegate void SetTextHandler(Control c, string text);
    public string ReportFieldName { get; set; }

    protected override IComponent[] CreateComponentsCore(IDesignerHost host)
    {
        var ctrl = (Label)host.CreateComponent(typeof(Label));
        var root = (Control) host.RootComponent;

        root.BeginInvoke(new SetTextHandler(SetText),
                         new object[] {ctrl, ReportFieldName});

        return new IComponent[]{ ctrl };
    }

    private void SetText(Control ctrl, string text)
    {
        ctrl.Text = text;
    }

}
```

Some obvious deficiencies:

- This item will only ever create a Label control
- This item will only ever set the text property of said label control based on the public string property.

To overcome these problems the item could be extended to act more like the base ToolboxItem (implementing a ctor accepting a Type parameter, allowing a dictionary of property name/values to be passed in to be set after the fact, etc)

Additionally this broke my drag and drop functionality from my Toolbox to the Design Surface and it was particularly frustrating because it wasn't overly apparent why.  The problem was in my DeserializeToolboxItem method of my Toolbox Service implementation.

Originally it looked like this:

```
ToolboxItem IToolboxService.DeserializeToolboxItem(object serializedObject)
{
   return (ToolboxItem) ((DataObject) serializedObject).GetData(typeof (ToolboxItem));
}
```

The problem was that the cast to ToolboxItem was returning null since the object was of type SurfaceToolboxItem so I modified the method to look like this:

```
ToolboxItem IToolboxService.DeserializeToolboxItem(object serializedObject)
{
   var data = (ToolboxItem) ((DataObject) serializedObject).GetData(typeof (ToolboxItem));

   return data ?? (ToolboxItem)((DataObject)serializedObject).GetData(typeof(SurfaceToolboxItem));
 }
```

Thus supporting both my extension as well as default ToolboxItem's.

Comment: Thanks for this one. It works on my end. I have created a custom ToolboxItem also that accepts different Types.

Answer (score 1):

This is not an answer, I just want to show what I have found with your problem. I think you should have your own way to access to your own `Toolbox`, and this `Toolbox` implements the interface `IToolboxService`, this interface has a method called `GetSelectedToolboxItem(IDesignerHost)`. And I think you have to implement that method to specify how you get the selected item, I think your `Toolbox` should have some control which holds the list of toolbox items, it can be a `ListBox`...

The second important thing is the `IDesignerHost`, as I understand this may be what you're interested in. It should have some relation with your `DesignSurface`. It has some events for you to interest, like this:

```
IDesignerHost host = {some method to get it};
host.TransactionClosed += (s,e) => {
  ICollection selected = ((ISelectionService)host.GetService(typeof(ISelectionService))).GetSelectedComponents();                
  IComponent[] comps = new IComponent[selected.Count];
  selected.CopyTo(comps, 0);
  string displayName = YourToolBox.GetSelectedToolboxItem(host).DisplayName;
  ((Control)comps[0]).Text = displayName;
};
```

I've tested in a project which implements a very complex `IDesignerHost`, it has a method for me to create the `host` to test. When dragging-n-dropping a control on the `DesignSurface`, it's still not affected by the code in `TransactionClosed`, I have to do something like `Resizing, Moving...` the control and after that `TransactionClosed` event is raised and it shows the `DisplayName` OK. I don't find any other event better, the most suitable event should be `ComponentAdded` or `ComponentAdding` but neither of them works.

I have one more question, the sample project I tried is a `CustomFormsDesigner` which runs as other normal Windows Forms application, it shows a Toolbox, a DesignSurface and a Properties Grid. I do everything after running it. But what about your case? I mean when you drag-n-drop your control onto your DesignSurface, you are still at design time in the Visual Studio window? or in your own application (as a Designer) window?

I have to say that, this problem is so complex to me. Thanks to you, I know about this kind of application.

Comment: Hey King King. A couple of things.  I should have been more clear: I am actually using System.ComponentModel.Design.DesignSurface so a lot of the nitty gritty of working with designers is abstracted away from me. My RootComponent is of type UserControl and your code does work, it fires every time a control is added to it, but my more specific problem is this: all of the "Tools" in my toolbox are of type Label and their DisplayName is set to the name of a field within the dataset of the report.  I need that DisplayName value so I know what field to tie the control to. But I'm open to suggestion

Comment: @abszero I've found a problem with my solution, it works only when I drag a control from another container on the form onto it, if dragging a new one from the Toolbox, it doesn't work. Why does it work for you? Look like that you have your own Toolbox with your own "Tools"?

Comment: I have a class that implements IToolboxService and I have a ListBox that contains several ToolboxItem that is married to this class. I then add this service to my DesignSurface.

Comment: @abszero I've just tried reading a little about IToolboxService and ToolboxItem, a ToolboxItem has a property called DisplayName, as I understand if I drag-n-drop 2 Labels from your toolbox, you will have to get the same DisplayName from 2 these Labels, right? and the problem is you don't know how to get that DisplayName?

Comment: Correct.   The interface IToolboxUser has a method called ToolPicked that can be implemented and it's signature looks like this ToolPicked(ToolboxItem) this happens after the tool has been invoked but it stands to reason if I can figure out where to get this plugged in at I could call toolBoxItem.CreateComponents(host, defaultValues).  I just don't know how to integrate that into a class and have it play well with everything else.

Comment: @abszero please see my update, not an answer, just some suggestion.

Comment: Hey King King.  Ya this has been pretty challenging. Honestly if the OnDragDrop event still worked I wouldn't be having this problem but Microsoft made a change to how dragging and dropping works so that event doesn't fire anymore. Controls can only be dragged and dropped to my DesignSurface at runtime because the DesignSurface isn't visibile during Design Time in VS.  I'm thinking it may be faster to write my own ToolboxItem that will set these properties for me when I instantiate the ToolboxItem. Thanks for all the feedback!